# Using Powershell ISE's intellisense in other terminal

Tags: powershell, terminal, intellisense

I'm a big fan of powershell ISE as a terminal. It has intellisense and syntax highlighting built in the shell and I just use it instead of the regular shell for everyday commands.

I would like to use Visual Studio Code instead, because the editor is much more powerfull and has support for a whole lot of languages and format. However the integrated shell is you basic Powershell terminal : no intellisense, no coloring (even with Powershell 5 installed on my computer).

Is there any way to add intellisense and coloring to my terminal, or use ISE's terminal in VSCode? or is there a plugin somewhere adressing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

The integrated PowerShell terminal on Visual Studio Code does have intellisense, so I'm unclear what you require here, are you sure it's not set to cmd.exe instead ?

[image: correct option]

On another note, follow this [setup guide](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/learning-powershell/using-vscode.md). In case you haven't already installed the PowerShell Extension.

Comment: It does indeed have autocompletion, what i refer to as 'intellisense' (probably mistakingly) is the ability to show a dropdown with completion option, much like inside the IDE. It helps, for instance, when there is an Enumeration and it becomes much easire to read the dropdown than to press tab repeatedly until you have cycled the options. Also, ISE shell has syntax highlighting which makes it much easier to read.